# How to determine if a mail fetch by imap base64 encoded?

Tags: python, email, base64, imap

I saved the whole message as xx.eml, but some mails body tells that mail is encoding by base64 at the first line, for example:

```
charset="utf-8" Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64   
charset="gb2312" Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
```

I tried to get the keys of `body[0][1]`, but there is no content-transfer-encoding field (only content-type).

How can I process that mails?

```
def saveMail(conn, num):

    typ, body = conn.fetch(num, 'RFC822')

    message = open(emldirPath + '\\' + num + '.eml', 'w+')
    message.write(str(email.message_from_string(body[0][1])))

    print email.message_from_string(body[0][1]).keys()
    #['Received', 'Return-Path', 'Received', 'Received', 'Date', 'From', 'To',
    # 'Subject', 'Message-ID', 'X-mailer', 'Mime-Version', 'X-MIMETrack',
    # 'Content-Type', 'X-Coremail-Antispam']

    message.close()
```

I found the problem, it's not decoding problem.

right mail as follow:
    ------=_Part_446950_1309705579.1326378953207
    Content-Type: text/plain; charset=GBK
    Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

what my program download:
    ------=_Part_446950_1309705579.1326378953207
    Content-Type: text/plain;
      charset="utf-8"
    Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

when my program save the .eml file, it change line after 'text/plain;'
therefore outlook express can't parse the mail
if I edit the line to ""Content-Type: text/html;charset="utf-8"",
it works

Now the question is: how to edit my program to not let it change line?

Comment: But why would you need to test for this? Just save the message as it is, if you decode the base64 it is possible you cannot open the saved file later. I mean, your .eml file should work perfectly well even with BASE64.

Comment: my .eml files are not work perfectly..,the body of the mails are not readable.(open by outlook express)

Comment: You got the point, it's hard to construct the mail after decoding. So how can I save the whole message as xxx.eml with all readable words?

Comment: Try [email.generator.Generator](http://docs.python.org/library/email.generator.html#email.generator.Generator) with a different `maxheaderlen`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Emails that are transfered as BASE64 must set `Content-Transfer-Encoding`. However you are most likely dealing with a MIME/Multipart message (e.g. both text/plain and HTML in the same message), in which case the transfer encoding is set separately for each part. You can test with `is_multipart()` or if `Content-Type` is `multipart/alternative`. If that is the case you use [walk](http://docs.python.org/library/email.message.html#email.message.Message.walk) to iterate over the different parts.

EDIT: It is quite normal to send text/plain using quoted-printable and HTML using BASE64.

```
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="=_d6644db1a848db3cb25f2a8973539487"
Subject: multipart sample
From: Foo Bar <foo@example.net>
To: Fred Flintstone <fred@example.net>

--=_d6644db1a848db3cb25f2a8973539487
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8

SOME BASE64 HERE
--=_d6644db1a848db3cb25f2a8973539487
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

AND SOME OTHER BASE64 HERE
```

Comment: yes,I print 'Content-Type' field,it shows "multipart/alternative" or multipart/mixed, I'll try walk()

Comment: I can decode payload now, but it's hard to construct the mail after decoding, any suggestion?

Comment: It pretty much depends on what the content is, you can try encoding it as [quoted-printable](http://docs.python.org/library/quopri.html) and change the content-transfer-encoding.